# What category name covers things that are designed to stand on the floor?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, phrase-requests, hypernyms

How to name a category of tall objects that are designed to stand on the floor as opposed to standing on a table? The tabletop objects are shorter than the freestanding objects and I cannot use "freestanding".

Comment: Floor-standing?

Comment: Tabletop is not a word that has an antonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chatkillah notes in the comments, *floor-standing* is used for things that are designed to stand on the floor. For example, the tall speakers that rest on the floor in home theatres are called [floor-standing speakers](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=3236453011).

Comment: 'floor-standing' seems the most accurate. I really needed this! thank you coleopterist and @chatkillah

Answer (score 0):

Table lamps go on the table while floor lamps go on the floor. Does this help you?

Comment: I'm not sure what your answer is. Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

The word is "***pedestal***". You may have heard of pedestal lamps, pedestal fans etc.